Dynamic created component don't find modules
I'm trying to render a component fully at runtime in a library with a custom generated template.
So far I have added the containerRef as following:
<ng-template #menuContainer></ng-template>
@ViewChild('menuContainer', { read: ViewContainerRef }) menuContainer!: ViewContainerRef;
Then I try to add a simple component as following:
const cmp = Component({
    selector: 'jit-menu',
    template: `<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu</button>
                <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
                <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
                <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
                </mat-menu>`,
    standalone: true,
    imports: [MatButtonModule, MatMenuModule]
})(class CustomComponent { });

this.menuContainer.createComponent(cmp)

This result with the error:
Export of name 'matMenu' not found!.
So I tried to change the template to just a button:
 template: <button mat-button>Menu</button>
And this works just fine.
In order to be able to render components at runtime I had to add this in the module:
 { provide: CompilerFactory, useClass: JitCompilerFactory, deps: [COMPILER_OPTIONS] },
oterhwise the error
The component 'CustomComponent' needs to be compiled using the JIT compiler, but '@angular/compiler' is not available. shows up.
I'm forced to use Angular & Material 16.2.0 and all this thing is because - at this day - it's impossible to give dynamic names to the template var ref doing something like
<ng-container *ngFor="let person of people"> <div #{{person.id}}>...</div> </ng-container> 
My question is: Why is Angular not recognizing the Module?
My main module includes a CustomMaterialModule with every single Material module imported and exported. I also tried including that module in the
imports: [MatButtonModule, MatMenuModule] without any changes in the errors.
EDIT: The same code worked in a fresh 18.2.0 Environment. Since the library is huge and I don't have time to debug for days I had to change approach.
I found this and I used it as a starting point to achieve a dynamic multi mat-menu.

Please explain the root problem you are trying to solve using this approach, there will surely be a simpler way to solve it, which does not involve dynamic created components

What I'm trying to do is a dynamic multilevel mat-menu.

Usually we have a for loop and recursively create the mat menu items, please share the data object and expected output, if a working example on stackblitz is given with the issue happening, that would be great for checking
